# This simple method doesn't work in Rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey guys
I'm new to rails. I'm practice what I've learned today about rails helper and ruby blocks by writing this code:

in /apps/helpers/home_helper.rb

```
module HomeHelper
  def each(from, to, by)
    x = from
    while x <= to
      yield x
      x = x + by
    end
  end
end
```

in /apps/views/index.html.erb

```
<p><%= each(2,16,3){|x| x } %></p>
```

But after I run the server, and navigate to the localhost:3000/home/index nothing in there.

anybody tells me what did I do wrong? Thanks

Comment: `each` is reserved. I'm assuming you are trying to override this default?

Comment: @Sam I don't intend to override the default, I just work make a simple code that can test what I learned today about block, I change the method name to myeach, but it's still nothing in the webpage.

Comment: @Sam: `each` is not a reserved word in ruby. it is a method of an `Enumerable`, but you are definitely free to implement your own each.

Comment: Did you find out what was wrong with your example?

Comment: @nathanvda I know what the problem was, I should use do end block in the three line style, But I still don't know why, so I ask [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5163896/456218) about this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to write that method. Do this instead:

```
<% [2, 16, 3].each do |n| %>
 <p><%= n %></p>
<% end %>
```

The reason for this, is that the method 'each' 1) is already a Ruby method on any Enumerable object and 2) it is poor practice to re-invent such a basic wheel.

Comment: He's not trying to implement over an array of those integers.

Comment: Actually this does not answer the question imho.

Answer (score 2):

As other people have said, there are better methods fro what you're trying to achieve built into ruby. Specifically the #step method:

```
2.step(16, 3) { |i| puts i }
```

Also note that your `index.html.erb` file should have been in `apps/views/home`.