# What's the difference between these two ways of using ruby blocks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is question is added to my [last one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150076/this-simple-method-doesnt-work-in-rails-helper).

The problem in my last question was solved by changing the following code:

```
<p><%= each(2,16,3){|x| x } %></p>
```

to

```
<p>
<% each(2,16,3) do |x| %>
<%= x %>
<% end %>
<p>
```

But I still don't know the difference between the one line style delimited by {} and 3 lines styles by using do and end tag

Comment: there's no difference =) user94154 suggested u using [2, 16, 3] instead of creating your own method... he didn't mean for you to just change the block style

Comment: There is do difference between using `do/end` and `{/}`. The difference is in the `<%= x %>` which occurs *inside* the 2nd example -- it will emit the value of `x` each time the each block is called.

Comment: @Staelen I know what you are talking about, I'm not trying to write my own, I just make a small test. and Now I realize both of them do have difference, the one line version don't have return value and <%= x %> have the return value of x

Comment: oh, yeah i missed that =P apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first version:

```
<p><%= each(2,16,3){|x| x } %></p>
```

takes the return value of the entire `each` method call and tries to output it. The second version:

```
<p>
  <% each(2,16,3) do |x| %>
    <%= x %>
  <% end %>
<p>
```

takes each individual item *one at a time* and outputs it (since you are evaluating the output *inside the block*). The actual return value of the `each` method is not used.

As mentioned by others, this only matters when you need to do some sort of output/calculation *inside* the block, which each value `yield`ed to the block; the rest is just semantics. The following are the same:

```
evens = (0..10).to_a.delete_if { |value| value.odd? }
```

and

```
evens = (0..10).to_a.delete_if do |value|
  value.odd?
end
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me this comprehensive answer, I have another question the actual return value of `each(2,16,3){|x| x }` is nothing right?

Comment: Every Ruby method has a return value. It's value of the last line in the method. In this case, it's the final test of the `while`, which evaluates to `nil`, so the return value is `nil`.

Comment: @nath I've figured out the reason, sorry for picking the answer this late :-)